# Como resolver o erro java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ao executar o rhinit() no R

Tags: r, hadoop

Estou integrando o `Hadoop` com `R` utilizando `Rhipe` e a minha configuração é a seguinte:

- Ubuntu 14.
- Hadoop 1.0.3
- R 3.2.2
- Rhipe 0.73.1

Ao iniciar no ambiente `R` o `rhinit()`   aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> rhinit() Rhipe: Using Rhipe.jar file Initializing Rhipe v0.73 Error in
>   .jnew("org/godhuli/rhipe/PersonalServer") :
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream

Já pesquisei bastante em outros foruns e até o momento ainda não obtive uma solução.

Conto com a ajuda dos senhores, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Parece estar relacionado ao Rhipe não conseguir encontrar o path do Hadoop. Segundo [este link](https://amalgjose.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/rhipe-installation/#comment-298), configurar algumas variáveis deveria resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema é causado porque as seguintes variáveis de ambiente não estão definidas corretamente :`PKG_CONFIG_PATH` e `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

**Configurando o R**

> exporte PKG_CONFIG_PATH = / usr / local / lib
>
> exporte LD_LIBRARY_PATH = / usr / local / lib

Também escreva estes comandos no console do  R:

> Sys.setenv (HADOOP_HOME = "/ usr / local / hadoop /")
>
> Sys.setenv (HADOOP_BIN = "/ usr / local / hadoop / bin")
>
> Sys.setenv (HADOOP_CONF_DIR = "/ usr / local / hadoop / conf")